# Symfony doesnt find css file

Tags: symfony

I've just done a fresh install of the latest Symfony version. Inside my `templates` folder I've created a new folder called website which contains a `base.html.twig` and a `home.html.twig`.

File structure: `templates/website/base.html.twig`

Inside my `public` directory I've created the following `css/app.css`. Now in my base I've done:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" type="text/css">`

Inside my stylesheet I'm just setting the body background colour to red so I know it works. For whatever reason it isn't loading my css. When I view source it appears as:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" type="text/css">`

and clicking the href I just get a Symfony 404. I cannot figure out why it  isn't loading my static CSS file.

I don't want to use Symfony Encore as thats overcomplicating things for my project. I have also tried `assets:install` command and nothing installed or changed.

**UPDATE:**

I installed and done a basic setup with Symfony Encore in the hope I could at least get some CSS working. Still get the exact same issue.

Comment: Which Symfony version are you using? Add a slash at the beginning of the path `{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}`

Comment: @Preciel No luck with the / at the start. Symfony version is 4.2.4

Comment: One more thing you can try: if you open `/css/app.css` in a browser and get the 404, try adding `public` to the path so that you'll have `public/css/app.css`. If you see your file then you know it's a config issue with the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `asset` funtion you have to install the component first with the following command:

```
composer require symfony/asset
```

That is really all there is to it if you do not wish to use webpack encore.

**Optional**: If you happen to use PHPStorm with the Symfony plugin, go to settings > symfony and change **Web Directory** from `app` to `public` for the new directory that Symfony 4 uses. This gives you all the autocomplete goodness and your references will work.

Comment: Already tried the composer require a couple times and made no difference. I also have setup PHPStorm in that way. I even tried install Symfony Encore

Comment: @Munch. my guess is this is a server issue. Maybe try with an absolute URL like so:

Comment: `{{ absolute_url(asset('css/app.css')) }}`

Answer (score -1):

You should store your static files inside the `assets` directory at the root of your project. So just place the `css`-folder with the `app.css`-file in `<root>/assets/css/app.css`

**Source**: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html

Comment: Didnt seem to make a difference. I moved my css file from `public/css` to `assets/css` and nothing changed

Comment: What server setup do you use?

Comment: It's a slightly modified version of `eko/docker-symfony`. My only change is removing the ELK part. I have this exact setup on another project which works and I cant see any differences